# How to restrict input data to mysql only [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am making application with FOSUserbundle and symfony2

but I can input 2byte caracter as userid.
How can I restrict input data.

I should check mysql level? or doctrine entity level  ?

According to @ManseUK help,

I have tried like

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User extends BaseUser
{


 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *　@Assert\MaxLength(limit="10", message="The tel number is too long.")
 *  @Assert\Regex("/[0-9]/")
 */
protected $tel1;
```

if I put more than 10 characters or letters other than 0-9 ,it is inputted normally.

Could you find some hint?

I am using FOSUserBundle and SonataAdminBundle

So there are three points to edit user Entity data.

when edit user data
in FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController

```
/**
 * Edit the user
 */
public function editAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.handler');

    $process = $formHandler->process($user);
    if ($process) {
        $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'profile.flash.updated');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->getRedirectionUrl($user));
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
        'FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

When regist user data
in FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegitrationController

```
public function registerAction()
{
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
    $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

    $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
    if ($process) {
        $user = $form->getData();

        $authUser = false;
        if ($confirmationEnabled) {
            $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
        } else {
            $authUser = true;
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
        }

        $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        if ($authUser) {
            $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

When manage data in SonataAdminBundle

```
namespace Acme\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeAdminBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

---

Thanks to @ManseUK

I have almost sloved the problem,but still mysterious thing remained.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="10", message="The tel number is too long.")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern="/[0-9]/",groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $tel1;
```

In a nutshell,

```
* @Assert\MaxLength(limit="10", message="The tel number is too long.")
```

works

but

```
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern="/[0-9]/",groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
```

dosen't work.

I can't put more than 10 letters,

but I can put other letters than [0-9] such as alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions as validation in Symfony ... something like this would work :

```
/* your user entity file */
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Regex("/[a-zA-Z0-9_]/")
     */
    protected $username;
}
```

[Documentation on the Regex constraint here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)

### Update

Just read the following [note on the FOSUserBundle forms section](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) :

> By default, the Registration validation group is used when validating a new user registration. Unless you have overridden this value in the configuration, make sure you add the validation group named Registration to your name property.

So you need something like this :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *        pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9_]/",
 *        groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
protected $username;
```

### Update 2

The problem is with your regex - its matching numbers .... but its not restricting the input to just numbers its matching numbers anywhere within the input ... you need to use something like the following :

```
^\d{1,10}$
```

- `^` means from the start
- `\d` means only numeric digits
- `{1,10}` means 1 to 10 occurrences, ie limit the length to 10
- `$` means to the end

Using this regular expression means you no longer need the `maxlength` assertion

Comment: @whitebear can you add your controller ? are you validating the form ?

Comment: I have copied my Controller,but it might be depending on FOSUserBundle.

Comment: @whitebear updated my answer - you need to add a validation group to your contraint/assertion

Comment: There still remains a little bit mysterious thing,I have added to main Topic.I apprecate your help

Comment: Thanks! I need to learn about Regex more. You are very helpful. it works perfect